# Replace Randomly Two Character in Python

Tags: python

I have a string

```
n = 'sophieMueller'
```

where I want to replace two random characters with two random ones of the following list:

```
replace = [
    'X', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'
]
```

Like this: s0phieM9eller

The following is almost working:

It gets a random indice of `n` (e. g. `n[2]` (`p`)) and replaces it with a random indice of `list` (e. g. `replace[6]` (`5`)).

```
n[randint(0, len(n))] = replace[randint(0, len(replace))]

print(''.join(n))
```

**My only problem is that when I want to replace more then one character I sometimes get an error. I guess it's because they try to replace the same indice at the same time? Any solution to this?**

```
n[randint(0, len(n))] = replace[randint(0, len(replace))]
n[randint(0, len(n))] = replace[randint(0, len(replace))]
```

Correct output for some runs and then:

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/test.py", line 16, in <module>
    n[randint(0, len(n))] = replace[randint(0, len(replace))]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: In Python, strings are immutable, meaning that you won't be able to edit them like this. It could be better to use slicing to create a new string (eg `replaced = my_string[:pos] + rand + my_string[pos+1:]` ).

Comment: The error you get is because randint is not like range, and can return the maximum value you pass as argument, which here would be n (or len(replace)), which leads to index out of range. Replace by randint(0, len(n)-1) and randint(0, len(replace)-1). But Miguel is right saying strings are immutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `randint(x, y)` produces a random integer between x and y *including both x and y*.

List indices start at zero and end at len(list)-1. If `randint` happens to pick the largest possible number - either `len(n)` or `len(replace)` - it can't find the corresponding item in the list because the list ended one item before that.

The code you need is:

```
n[randint(0, len(n)-1)] = replace[randint(0, len(replace)-1)]
```